# A function not following Rolle's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

This is just out of curiosity. Does there exist a function f differentiable on $(a,b]$ that does not follow Rolle's theorem? (a,b are real numbers)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b]$, then it is also differentiable on $(a,b)$ and as long as $f$ satisfies the other conditions for Rolle's Theorem, Rolle's Theorem still applies.

Comment: @Kyle The issue is what happens at $a$. Is the function defined there? Continuous there?

Comment: @alex.jordan What if it is continuous at a?

Comment: Then you have the conditions of Rolle's theorem: continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ (a subset of $(a,b]$.)

Comment: True! If f is defined on a but not continuous on a like you posted below it does not follow the theorem

Comment: @alex.jordan I got it now.  I was assuming the function was still satisfying the continuity as in Rolle's Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Rolle's theorem presumes the function to be equal at the endpoints. Is your $f$ defined at $a$? If so, it need not be continuous at $a$. So we could have $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1/x&x\in(0,1]\\1&x=0\end{cases}$$ and that might be an example you are looking for.

Comment: This is true since f is not continuous on [0,1] right?

Comment: $f$ being discontinuous allows for Rolle's consequence to fail. If $f$ were defined and continuous at $a$, then you are back to having the conditions of Rolle's theorem. (Note Rolle's Theorem only refers to differentiability on $(a,b)$, not any larger interval.)